# Setting x-axis of a plot on each loop

Tags: r

I have a block of code:

```
window<-5
start<-3
n<-1

seq1 <- seq(1:40)
mat<-matrix(seq1,40)


while(1+window<=length(mat[,1]))
{
  kd<-matrix(as.integer(mat[n:(n+window-1),1]))
  Sys.sleep(0.2)
  plot(kd,col="blue",xlab="Rohdaten",ylab="values",xlim=c(start+n,start+n+window-1))

  n<-n+1
}
```

I have this expectation, that on each loop two x-axis and y-axis are changed and see the values on the plot. but I cant see the value.What should I do to have values too?. If I am changing this my code to

```
plot(kd,col="blue",xlab="Rohdaten",ylab="values")
```

I can see the values but on the x-axis I have no the correct values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix `kd` that you are creating has different indicees than your original matrix. Therefore the indicees always go from 1 to 5. You should just plot the entire matrix with your xlimits.

```
while(n+window<=length(mat[,1]))
{
  Sys.sleep(0.2)
  plot(mat,col="blue",xlab="Rohdaten",ylab="values",xlim=c(start+n,start+n+window-1))
  n<-n+1
}
```

Then you can of course also add a `ylim`, if you don't always want the entire range of y-values in the matrix.